# Alternative for campagnolo rim brake release

Tags: road-bike, rim-brake, campagnolo

I bought a used road bike for a great price, it came with a shimano 105 groupset, but the brake it's a Campagnolo centaur.

It's a wonderful brake, but every time when I need to remove the wheel it's need to tighten the barrel adjuster to open the brake.
I am aware that the campagnolo rim breake release system it's a button in levers, but I would like to know if it is possible to place a release lever directly on the brake, just like the system on the shimano brakes.

Comment: Only some Shimano brake levers have the cable release.  Most have a release on the caliper itself.   Consider your cheapest option might be to change out the calipers for something with a Quick release.

Comment: I remember seeing brake quick release adapters with 80s centerpull brakes, where they could be used to disable the front brake that was considered dangerous. No idea if they are still made and whether they are safe to use at all.

Comment: Cheap Traktor levers have the same kind of release as Campagnolo levers, but I was assuming the OP had brifters, so this would not be a reasonable swap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Closest thing out there is the Shimano SM-CB90 in-line brake QR, which exists to be paired with direct mount road calipers but would solve this problem too.
[image: Shimano SM-CB90]

Comment: They cost around 20€ per unit.

Answer (score 1):

I've never heard of such a thing. If such a gadget did exist, it would probably cost more than Shimano 105 brakes.

The closest thing I can think of is a cable splitter, intended to be used on some travel bikes: a splitter is two pieces that screw together. Using one wouldn't be less trouble than what you're doing now.